# Why use an integer versus a double?

Tags: java, integer, double

I have code for two versions of the same function: one iterative and one recursive. I want to know why the return type is `int`. What does it afford you? Why can't the return type be `double`?

```
public static int iterative(int n){
  int var=1;
  int var1=1;
  int var2=1;

  if (n<=1) {
    return 1;
  }

  for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
    var=var1+var2+1;
    var2=var1;
    var1=var;
  }

  return var;
}

private static int recursive(int n){
  if (n<=1){
    return 1;
  }

  return rec(n-1)+rec(n-2)+1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(iter(10));
}
```

Comment: Guessing because that's what the author wanted.  The return types could be double, or float, or long, ......

Comment: Why should it? The result of fibonnaci is always an integer. So theres no need to waste memory for double (double 64 bit, integer 32 bit)

Comment: If you change `private static int` to `private static double` it should still work - at least for `rec`

Comment: the task says   L(0) = 1
        L(1) = 1
        L(n) = L(n - 1) + L(n - 2) + 1  when  n > 1. and i had to print numbers from 0 to 30. what happens when it will be in double ?

Comment: The result will look like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0 ...

Comment: @user - only one number is printed

Comment: @cricket_007 true for the code posted above. But according to susannees comment the first 30 fibonacci numbers will be printed out in the way like in my comment

Comment: thank you guys i got it now!

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly define the function to return a `double`, in the same way you could define it to return a `String`. The formats are capable of representing the values you'll be returning, there's just no reason to do it.

- The function you're computing (a modified Fibonacci sequence) is defined over the set of integers - in fact, only positive integers. It will never produce a value that can not be represented by an `int`.
- `double` (and `String`) is more expensive in both space and computation.
- The return type is a strong indication to other developers what kind of data to expect. Returning a `double` that will only contain `1, 2, 3, ...` is to some extent misleading.

So use `double` if you like; it will work just fine. But the question is more "why?" than "why not?".

Comment: @susannee No problem and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer was helpful, check out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).